# Is it permissible for a woman to have criteria other than being religious-commited when accepting a marriage proposal?

Tags: nikah, women

A [shahih](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#.E1.B9.A2a.E1.B8.A5.C4.AB.E1.B8.A5) hadith states:

> A woman may be married for four things: her wealth, her lineage, her beauty and her religious commitment. Seek the one who is religiously-committed, may your hands be rubbed with dust.
>
> [Narrated by Bukhari-Muslim]

Say, a woman is, being proposed by a number of good men, being asked if the man can propose her, being asked if there is no other man proposing her at the moment.

Say she choses one of them.

My question is, if she puts some other criteria aside from this man's religious commitment, is it permissible in Islam according to Quran and Hadith (and the above one)?

Let's say these criteria are like a man:

- taller than her
- who can speak English (because she's learning English)
- with a beard
- that is not too fat nor too skinny
- man that is wiser and more resolute than her. And so forth.

If she does have a man's *being religiously-committed* as part of the criterion for accepting his/their marriage proposal(s), is it permissible to include other criteria, such as those mentioned above, while doing so?

Comment: You can ask Allah anything. The point is that, God-consciousness is the best thing you can ask for. All other things are secondary. My wife says that all the things she asked for, like the things you mentioned, Allah fulfilled them.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that , man being pious and good muslim, should be TOP priority for woman, besides that if woman has other conditions like he should be tall, handsome, mature, sensible etc, then nothing wrong in such expectation. Its her right to marry the man she likes. So having worldly conditions is not haram in any way, but encouraged, as partners should be compatible to each other for better understanding and living

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you please enclose some quoted Hadith or Quran regarding your answer, for me to keep it in mind? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Making a choice is not prohibited in Islam but the most essential thing is God fearing. You can chose up any man as long as he is pious man.